# How to Order these list of string according to its version

Tags: c#

Adding some sample data

```
var list0 = new List<string>() { "MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.8","MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.4","MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.7","MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.12", "MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.11", "MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.10","MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.3", "All" };
```

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"All", "master-1.2107.120.0","master-1.2107.124.0", "master-1.2107.136.0","master-1.2107.122.0", "master-1.2107.136.0", "master-1.2107.138.0" };
```

```
var list3 = new List<string>() {"All", "users_yingrt_saturn-1.2104.3.2", "users_yingrt_saturn-1.2104.3.4", "users_yingrt_saturn-1.2104.3.5", "users_yingrt_saturn-1.2104.3.7" }
```

What I tried to solve.

```
list0 = list0.OrderByDescending(o => o).ToList();
foreach (var i in list0) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

Trying to create some logic to sort the list according to its version mentioned in it.
Expected Output :
`MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.12, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.11, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.10, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.8, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.7, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.4, MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.3, All`

A similar result for other lists as well.
A possible solution can be if will able to Split its version and make a dictionary <key, value> value as version and sort on top of version.
Not able to achieve in code. Need some Help!!!

Comment: MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.10 precedes MAS_Prod_1.2107.0.8 in an alphabetical sort.

Comment: [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248603/8967612) will get you 90% of the way. You'd need to write a custom IComparer to handle "All", or simply push it to the end of the list after sorting.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Common nature all has a version as suffix either starting '_' or '-' and having four decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). You can create a semver class, parse the version and order by it. It's not very clear if the `1` before the first dot is part of the versioning or the name, but you can easily add another field if it has to be orderable too.

If you can't match the semver pattern, you can return a deafult version. In this case, I'm returning 0.0.0, so it will be the first version and will fulfill your requirements for the `All` to be the first. If you want to be the last, you can change it so it'll return the `int.MaxValue` for all properties.

```
public class SemVer : IComparable<SemVer>
{
    public SemVer()
    {
    }   
    
    public int Major { get; set; }
    public int Minor { get; set; }
    public int Patch { get; set; }
    
    public static SemVer Parse(string input)
    {
        Match match = Regex
            .Match(input, @"(?<major>\d+)\.(?<minor>\d+)\.(?<patch>\d+)$");
        if(match.Success){
            return new SemVer(){
                Major=int.Parse(match.Groups["major"].Value),
                Minor=int.Parse(match.Groups["minor"].Value),
                Patch=int.Parse(match.Groups["patch"].Value),
            };
        }
        return new SemVer();
    }

    public int CompareTo(SemVer other)
    {
        int result = Major.CompareTo(other.Major);
        if(result==0){
            result = Minor.CompareTo(other.Minor);
        }
        if(result==0){
            result = Patch.CompareTo(other.Patch);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
list0 = list0.OrderByDescending(x=>SemVer.Parse(x)).ToList();
list1 = list1.OrderByDescending(x=>SemVer.Parse(x)).ToList();
list3 = list3.OrderByDescending(x=>SemVer.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write a class to store `Name`, `Major version`, `Minor version` and `Mini version` then Order it by each property.

```
public class Version
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Major { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
    public int Minor { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
    public int Mini { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
   
    public Versions(string version)
    { 
        var splittedVersion = version.Split('.');
        this.Name = splittedVersion[0];
        if(splittedVersion.Length == 4)  //Condition check for "All"
        {
            this.Major = splittedVersion[1];
            this.Minor = splittedVersion[2];
            this.Mini = splittedVersion[3];
        }
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
         if(this.Major == int.MinValue && this.Major == int.MinValue && this.Mini == int.MinValue)
              return this.Name;
          else
              return $"{this.Name}.{this.Major}.{this.Minor}.{this.Mini}";
    }
     
    
}
```

Now Parse your list elements into `Version` class and order it based on versions.
Like,

```
using System.Linq;

....
var results = list0 
      .Select(x => new Version(x)) //Convert list of string into list of Version class
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Major) //First order by Major version
      .ThenByDescending(x => x.Minor)  //Then order by Minor version
      .ThenByDescending(x => x.Mini)  //Then order by mini version
      .ToList();   //Convert IEnumerable to List
```

Now print updated result,

```
foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: For everything except `Name`, OP could use the existing `System.Version` class, which already implements the desired sorting logic.

Comment: @Heinzi, cool, I was not aware of it. I will take a look and will update my answer with `System.Version`

Comment: @Heinzi, there is a corner case here `"All"`, does `System.Version` supports `"All"` as a version. If not then check out my answer it supports "All" as a version name

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more advanced SemVer-sorting, I can recommend you to use [NuGet.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Versioning/) or my own package [Vernuntii.SemVer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vernuntii.SemVer). Both have a static `SemanticVersion.Parse(versionStringToParse)` method and both have a implementation of an `IComparer<SemanticVersion>` called `VersionComparer` ([Nuget.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Versioning/)) or `SemanticVersionComparer` ([Vernuntii.SemVer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vernuntii.SemVer)).